# UE4 Move spline along other spline

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, spline, unreal-blueprint

There are 2 splines: static and movable. the movable one must move along the static one but keeping the distance between its points [image]. Static spline doesn't move but it can be it can be added or changed in length in real time (as at video as in the video below). A movable spline can be attached to something, so you cannot predefine the movement of each point. It works for me, but the distance between the points gets lost (but should not)
Thanks in advance for any answer that will help me with this problem.

My algorithm:

1. Get location of movement spline point
2. Get position of movement spline point at static spline
3. Set position of movement spline point to found pos at step 2

Answer (score 1):

[Spline Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1yFR.jpg)

Not sure if this is entirely what you're after, without seeing a copy of your current blueprint, (I tried to ask for previously, however it wasn't deemed an answer and was removed by the moderator) I use this to provide a set distance along a spline to generate what ever I please. If I could see a copy of your working blueprint I might be able to help, I might not :-)